# In which way do_filp_open call dentry_open in linux kernel 2.6

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm working on linux kernel 2.6.

In function do_sys_open,  there is a call to filp_open:

`struct file *f = do_filp_open(dfd, tmp, flags, mode, 0);`

This function somewhere calls dentry_open(). I don't understand where this function is called.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: where exactly is called dentry_open starting from sys_open and then do_filp_open. then?which other functions are called to arrive at dentry_open?

Comment: see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=dentry_open

Comment: yes but no one of these functions with dentry open is called directly from filp open.. It's driving me crazy

Comment: and is http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=2.6.34;i=dentry_open